# images with invalid jpeg marker

Tags: image, jpeg

I encountered a website where the images consistently throws 'invalid jpeg marker' error when downloaded. I am wondering is it possible that they are intentionally doing something which causes this error for most of the users who try to download and use their images?

I want to protect the jpeg resources of my website from unauthorised use. Is it possible to really change something in jpeg header or meta tags so that jpg images display fine on browser but if someone downloads it for their own use it throws an error 'invalid jpeg marker'?
(I don't intend to discuss alternative ways of protecting images online or the limitations of it.)

Comment: Are you sure the images were saved correctly? Do the downloaded images show correctly when you open them again in a browser? When you do that, what does the browser say is the file format?

Comment: To expand on @Juhana's: Most browsers can display a PNG *even though* the file extension is .jpg. Your local software is not smart enough to do the same.

Comment: @Juhana my question is NOT how to view those files correctly. Internet is full of such questions anyway and there is not need to ask it here. My question is how to intentionally do something similar so that people( some of them atleast) who tries to download and use images from my website experience similar issues.

Comment: I only asked because a) it's very likely that they're not jpgs and you should check and b) it's very unlikely that browsers use somehow different algorithm than every other software, which is also a reason why you should check. Because it's probable that the entire question is based on a false premise.

Answer (score 0):

If it can display on a browser, it can display on something else. What is likely happening is that the decoder you are using to view when downloaded is more strict than your web browser. I presume you are not using your browser to view them after downloading.

You could run the "file" command to make sure the images are actually JPEGs. If so, there are a number of programs available to analyze the structure of a JPEG stream. You could use one to see what's going on with the image. You may have some odd marker ordering or possibly the JPEG image does not occur right at the start of the file stream. I've seen some weird JPEGs where there were extra bytes after the APPn marker and before the next JPEG marker. Some decoders ignored the extra bytes others puked.

Comment: thanks for your reply. My question is basically than can i myself convert my JPEGs to those 'weird JPEGs  where there were extra bytes after the APPn marker and before the next JPEG marker' so that if a person tries to download my jpegs and use them, he encounters some or similar issues in viewing those files on their system.